# how to make term reference field choose term from a multi level taxonomy vocabulary

Tags: views, feeds, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy voc 'area' that has three levels, region > province > town and city.

I then have a content type 'members' which has these three term reference fields that retrieve region, province and town and city respectively from the area vocabulary.

I used feeds to transfer a csv file of members with one member per row, each with region / province / town city. The result after the feed upload looks great.

Using views to make a block and page I have contextual filters show those same terms and they expand quite nicely via a block from region to a province page, each showing how many 'members' there are per page in parenthesis, drilling down to a town and city page. It's all very nice.

However when I try to manually enter a Member I need to enter region, province and town city using a a select field each time. Using hierarchical select doesn't work because I think it doesn't know which level to choose a term from. The result always skews the view, because for example, province field is choosing a town city, or vice versa, or a region. I do not know how to make it choose the level in the select field i want.

I am clueless. I do not even know if I am asking the correct question because I do not know if my error lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Simple Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs), it is less buggy than the more complex one.